# Saving files downloaded from Urlretrieve to another folder other

Tags: python, urllib

Currently have this working and its downloading the files correctly but is placing them in the same folder where it is being ran from, but how would i go about say moving these to c:\downloads or something like this?

```
urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*filename* is basically your reference to the file and where it is stored. Using the following command

```
fullfilename = os.path.join(myPath, filename)
urllib.urlretrieve(url, fullfilename)
```

You should be able to store it at *myPath*.

Don't forget to place

```
import os
```

at the top of your script..